# ASP.NET core startup fatal error - impossible to run the project with normal .net references

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dependencies

[image: Startup Fatal Error - host.Run exception]

I have .NET Core 1.1.1 web project that I can't run properly. I'm compiling against .NET 452 or/and .NET 462, this project has several regular .NET libraries references. The exception that I'm getting is:

```
System.AggregateException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=An error occurred while writing to logger(s).
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.LogCritical(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, Exception exception, String message, Object[] args)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
       at ClientFacingWeb.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\..\ClientFacingWeb\Program.cs:line 18
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2147467262
       Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.Internal.ConfigurationManagerInternal' to type 'System.Configuration.TimeSpanValidator'.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManagerInternalFactory.get_Instance()
            at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
            at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_IndentSize()
            at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.InitializeSettings()
            at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message, String category)
            at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.DebugLogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
            at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
       InnerException:
```

The message being printed in the console is:

```
Compilation=DEBUG
Environment=Development
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The configuration is read only.
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection.BaseRemoveAt(Int32 index)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal.get_Section()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InitializeSockets()
   at System.Net.IPAddress.InternalParse(String ipString, Boolean tryParse)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.CreateIPEndpoint(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListenerPrimary.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<StartAsync>b__8_0(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.ListenerPrimary.<StartAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.CreateServer(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The configuration is read only.
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection.BaseRemoveAt(Int32 index)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal.get_Section()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InitializeSockets()
   at System.Net.IPAddress.InternalParse(String ipString, Boolean tryParse)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.CreateIPEndpoint(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListenerPrimary.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<StartAsync>b__8_0(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.ListenerPrimary.<StartAsync>d__12.MoveNext()<---
```

If I remove those regular .NET references the project executes successfully. 
I'm not able to identify which one of the references is causing the error.

I have look into the output window too see the loaded modules, and none of the loaded modules are different if I use, have or not my regular .NET project/library references.